# How to filter offsetting values from Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame with several hundred rows of values, either positive or negative.  In most cases, for each positive value there is a direct negative offset.  However, there are some cases where a positive value is split into two or more (generally not more than 3) offsets, or a negative is split into two or more positive offsets.  Ultimately, I would like to filter out all the offsets to a new data frame in which the sum of the rows equals 0. In the original data frame I would be left with the values which do not have an offset (and would sum to something other than 0).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'AAD', 'AAE', 'AAF', 'AAG', 'AAH', 'AAI', 'AAJ'],
'Value': [300, 1500, -450, -300, -700, -800, 20, -75, 75, -31]})

    ID  Value
0  AAA    300
1  AAB   1500
2  AAC   -450
3  AAD   -300
4  AAE   -700
5  AAF   -800
6  AAG     20
7  AAH    -75
8  AAI     75
9  AAJ    -31
```

So the new data frame would look like this:

```
print (pairs_df)
    ID  Value
0  AAA    300
1  AAB   1500
2  AAD   -300
3  AAE   -700
4  AAF   -800
5  AAH    -75
6  AAI     75
```

And the original would be:

```
print (df)
    Id  Value
0  AAC   -450
1  AAG     20
2  AAJ    -31
```

Comment: Are the offsets ID based?

Comment: Only that an offset will not fall under the same ID as the original value.  Think of ID as one company charging another company (or companies).

Comment: Not clear enough. How do we determine offset. Explain knowing all I need is to understand what you want done and I am not a subject matter specialist.

Comment: Values and their offsets are randomly scattered across rows, sometimes it's a 1:1 match, and sometimes 1:2 or 1:3 (or more?).  The only way to determine an offset is to iterate each value against all others until a match is found, as determined by value + offset(s) = 0, then pull those values and offsets out of the data set.  The goal is to understand which residual ID rows are left over which cannot be offset.  The ID for the value will be different from the ID of the offset.